# OAuth - Consumer secret in open-source applications

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm creating a Wordpress plugin for collectively managing a Twitter 
account. I want to allow the user to add accounts via the Admin panel 
similar to the way twitterfeed.com does.

However, the only way I can see of doing it is to get the user to sign 
in to their account, register the application under a unique name and 
paste in the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret to my application.

What are the security repercussions of simply 
distributing a single Consumer Key and Consumer Secret with my plugin, 
so that I can get the Request Token and Access Token and minimise the 
effort required by the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, the biggest issue (I'm not sure it's necessarily a security issue) is that someone will use your Key/Secret inappropriately (let's say a spamming application) causing it to get revoked.  At that point, every instance of your plug-in will fail to authenticate and you'll have to generate a new one, incorporate it in your plug-in and get all the users to update.  Which is probably not ideal...

Ars Technica had a pretty good write-up about it [here](http://arstechnica.com/security/guides/2010/09/twitter-a-case-study-on-how-to-do-oauth-wrong.ars)

Comment: I hit here searching how to protect twitter consumer secret. This discussion is now nearly 2+ years old now. I wonder why does twitter not support oauth 2.0 yet which has concept of intermediate auth code and does not require consumer secret to be with the mobile client. any insights?

Comment: @Sushil, same reason they don't support IPv6: it'd have taken more resources than they'd have been willing to invest to implement it till now, but they might fix it later.